# Trying to add “ and cats” just after “dogs” but the “s” from the “dogs” left out everytime

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to replace add `" and cats"` just after `"dogs"` but I can't seem to get the right output with only the `"s"` from the `"dogs"` left out everytime.

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    String message = "I love dogs! I have a dog named Coco. My dog's very smart!";
    int i = 0;
    
    while(message.indexOf("dogs") >= 0)
    {
      i = message.indexOf("dogs");
      String sub1 = message.substring(0 , i + 3);
      String sub2 = message.substring(i + 4);
      message = sub1 + " and cats" + sub2;
    }
    System.out.println(message);    
  }
}
```

Right now my output is `"I love dog and cats! I have a dog named Coco. My dog's very smart!"`. But the `"s"` is missing and I can't figure out how to fix that.

Comment: I would recommend using [`String::replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence)).

Comment: the upper bound in substring is exclusive, so use `i+4` for the first part, too

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be overcomplicating things I would just use [replace](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-replace):

```java
String message = "I love dogs! I have a dog named Coco. My dog's very smart!";
message = message.replace("dogs", "dogs and cats");
System.out.println(message);
```

This returns:

```
I love dogs and cats! I have a dog named Coco. My dog's very smart!
```

The problem with your code is the first substring should be:

```
String sub1 = message.substring(0 , i + 4);
```

to include the final s. But then the while would be infinite as the string "dogs" is still there in the `message` string, you should change the while to check only after the previous find by incrementing the `i` and check from that index on:

```
while(message.indexOf("dogs", i) >= 0)
{
  i = message.indexOf("dogs");
  String sub1 = message.substring(0 , i + 4);
  String sub2 = message.substring(i + 5);
  message = sub1 + " and cats" + sub2;
  i++;
}
System.out.println(message);
```

which outputs:

```
I love dogs and cats I have a dog named Coco. My dog's very smart!
```